# html checkbox with an 'x' instead of the traditional tick

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox

is it possible display a 'x' for an html checkbox when we click on it. Traditionally on ie, (on winxp and greater) it appears as a 'tick' mark. Can we change this? Or else what is the alternative to this in asp.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can hack something using images instead of a real checkbox, using javascript to change the image selection

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are talking to Web Application or Windows application.
Let's assume that you meant Web application.
You can't change normal input, it's something in system settings.

However, you can put Javascript that will put CSS images instead.
Example: http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/ or
http://aaronweyenberg.com/90/pretty-checkboxes-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Ajax Control Toolkit's ToggleButton Control:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx

I think it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

there's [fancy-forms](http://lipidity.com/fancy-form/) to accomplish exactly this